# NewtonSoft Deserialize nested JSON Blue Prism

Tags: c#, json, nested, ocr, blueprism

I'm using Blue Prism to call the Microsoft Computer Vision API to recognize text from a PDF.

After getting the JSON response, Blue Prism transforms it into a Collection (DataTable) using either the JSON Utility from Blue Prism, or the Action Provided on the Microsoft Computer Vision skill: Get Read Operation Response.

Problem: Blue Prism is unable parse the JSON text into a Collection in certain cases due to a data type error.

Can someone sugest a code to convert **this type of JSON structure** into a DataTable which Blue Prism can read?

I have attached pastebin links for the 2 JSON (Body is limited to 30000 characters, can't copy them here).

READABLE in Blue Prism (contains special characters !"#$%&/()"'):

> > https://pastebin.com/QMPCiQty

NOT READABLE in Blue Prism:

> > https://pastebin.com/V3HVssQz

Blue Prism gives the following errors:

Using "Get Read Operation Response" action:

> > Internal : Unexpected error Data Type mismatch in array: Element '3' has type instead of expected type 'System.Double'

Using "JSON Utility from Blue Prism":

> > Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Data Type mismatch in array

I tried to parse the nested JSON into a datatable by creating the public classes using the tool provided at json2csharp.com, and then point to them and write to the data table. I also tried by not creating the classes, just parse the JSON directly to the data table by pointing to the property **recognitionResults**.

Without classes:

> DataSet ds = JObject.Parse(json_txt)["recognitionResults"].ToObject();

With classes:

> DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_txt, (typeof(DataTable)));

Classes:

```
public class Word
{
    public List<double> boundingBox { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string confidence { get; set; }
}

public class Line
{
    public List<double> boundingBox { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Word> words { get; set; }
}

public class RecognitionResult
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public double clockwiseOrientation { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public List<Line> lines { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<RecognitionResult> recognitionResults { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how the **nested** collection should look like in Blue Prism:
[Blue Prism Nested Response Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnqVc.png)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a sample of the JSON you are trying to deserialize -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: What Blue Prism version are you on? This can be made way easier than you're making it in some of the latest versions of 6.x.

Comment: @dbc I edited the question, please check it.

Comment: @esqew I'm using version 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 6 or greater you should give a look to Blue Prism DX, a division of the community where users can interchange VBOs and knowledge. This problem has been solved:

[JSON Utility Blue Prism](https://digitalexchange.blueprism.com/dx/entry/9648/solution/blue-prism-json-utility)

> This utility provides the capability to parse JSON into a collection and also to turn a collection into JSON.

Comment: It doesn't always work, please refer to the two files attached on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @MikeRs's answer, this is easily solvable using the Blue Prism DX, but instead using the [Microsoft Computer Vision skill](https://digitalexchange.blueprism.com/dx/entry/3439/solution/vision-skill-azure-cloud-20).

Send the file through the skill and use the outputs to retrieve the analysis in Blue Prism-formatted Data Items.

Comment: As I explained in the question, both, the Microsoft Vision Skill, and the JSON Utility from Blue Prism DX, both work on most of the cases on parsing the JSON into collection. Not always.

Comment: @David Which version of the Microsoft Azure Computer Vision skill are you working with? My understanding is that v2.0 of the Skill (linked in the above answer) no longer encounters this issue.

Comment: I'm still getting the same

Internal : Unexpected error Data Type mismatch in array: Element '3' has type instead of expected type 'System.Double'

Error

Comment: I did upgrade to v2.0 but I'm still getting the same errors. Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in the updated JSON utility here: https://digitalexchange.blueprism.com/dx/entry/3439/solution/utility---json

If you use JSON skipping Jarray action

[image]

you can parse the json you gave as example above. This works on both your OK and NOT OK json examples. For anybody on old code this update came in 11th October 2022 so very possible not everyone has updated the utility since then.

Here is a snippet of the code working from process level, you need utility file management and utility json imported to use it but paste it into your process studio to see example working

https://pastebin.com/nsepwmzq
(raw xml of Json section to paste pastebin link)

```
<process name="__selection____default"><stage stageid="367b5fe1-8088-4385-b4b3-ae3b248e8e07" name="JSON To Collection" type="Action"><subsheetid>224ec212-b503-4625-acd5-ab43b64c4f8c</subsheetid><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="15" y="15" /><inputs><input type="text" name="json" friendlyname="json" expr="[Data1]" /></inputs><outputs><output type="collection" name="Result" friendlyname="Result" stage="VAR - JSON Config" /></outputs><resource object="Utility - JSON" action="JSON to Collection (skipping JArray)" /></stage></process>
```